# How to write HDF5 datasets to a np.array of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, hdf5, h5py

I'm writing a small script that writes data from an HDF5 file into a matrix for further analysis.

The structure of the file is the following:
the file consists of several groups named accordingly with the groupname_template in the code below (e.g. '0, 0', '0, 1' and so on). Each group has at least one dataset inside.

I want to create a matrix of dictionaries, each element of which would be a dictionary consisting of datasets names and the corresponding data.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import re

loaddir = r'C:\Users\User\Documents\data reading test\test_datafile.hdf5'
matrix_dict = np.full((10,10), {})
groupname_template = re.compile('\d+, \d+')

with h5py.File(loaddir, 'r') as loadedfile:
    for group in loadedfile.keys():
        if bool(re.match(groupname_template, group)):
            for key, value in loadedfile[group].items():
                matrix_dict[eval(group)[0], eval(group)[1]][key] = value[:]
```

However, when I try to write a dictionary to a matrix cell, it also gets copied into all the cells that were filled prior to that, which results in a matrix containing datasets only from the last group.

I tried different syntaxes and methods, but the issue is still there.

So I'm open to any suggestions to what causes this weird propagation of datasets.

Comment: `np.full((10,10), {})` creates an array with all elements being the SAME dict.

Comment: An object dtype array, like a list, contains references to objects.  `[{}]*3` makes a list containing 3 references to the same `dict`.  You have to ensure the `matrix_dict` contains 100 separate `dict`, either at creation, or later in your iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj I figured that might be the case. So how does one create a 2D array of dictionaries, where every cell is independent of one another?

Comment: good old fashion iteration!  Each dict has to be created with its own `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you load the dataset name/value pairs to `matrix_dict`. You have to create 1 dictionary to hold all of the dataset name/value pairs for each group, then assign that to the appropriate `(i,j)` index in `matrix_dict`.

I modified your code to demonstrate how I think you want this to work. It uses
a simple HDF5 example file I created (with 4 groups / 3 datasets each). Code for that file is at the end.

Notes on my example below.

- I changed the name of `matrix_dict` to `arr_of_dict` b/c it is a
  NumPy array. I did this for clarity b/c an array and a matrix are different object types. You are creating an array. A matrix is a specialized 2-D "array-like" object created with `np.matrix()`. The NumPy `np.matrix()` doc says: "*It is no longer recommended to use this class*".
- I created `arr_dict` to load the dataset name/value pairs from each
  group into a single dictionary. It is assigned to the group `(i,j)`
  index after the loop.
- I changed the variable names generated by `group.items()` from `key,value` to `ds_name, ds_obj` to improve readability (and reinforce they are the dataset name and H5 object).

**Code to retrieve groups/datasets and load into a np.array of dictionaries:**

```
with h5py.File(loaddir, 'r') as loadedfile:
    for group in loadedfile.keys():
        print(f'working on group: {group}')
        if bool(re.match(groupname_template, group)):
            print(f'reading datasets in group: {group}')
            arr_dict = {}
            for ds_name, ds_obj in loadedfile[group].items():
                arr_dict[ds_name] = ds_obj[:]
            arr_of_dict[eval(group)[0], eval(group)[1]] = arr_dict
```

**Code to print the values in the np.array created above:**

```
for i in range(arr_of_dict.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr_of_dict.shape[1]):
        arr = arr_of_dict[i,j]
        if len(arr):
            print(f'\ndatasets from group ({i}, {j})')
            [print(f'dataset {k}:\n{v}')  for k,v in arr.items() ]
```

**Code to create my example file:**

```
group_names = ['0, 0', '0, 1', '1, 0', '1, 1']
loaddir = 'test_datafile.hdf5'

with h5py.File(loaddir, 'w') as h5f:
    for group in group_names:
        grp = h5f.create_group(group)
        for i in range(3):
            arr = np.random.random(10).reshape(5,2)
            grp.create_dataset(f'ds_{i}', data=arr)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've already tried making an intermediate dictionary for transferring datasets into the array, but, apparently, did it in a wrong way. Now it works as intended.

Comment: Yeah, the dtype for a `np.array` of dictionaries is `np.object` / 'O', not `dict`. So you can't use dictionary syntax to write to `arr_of_dict[i,j]`. That's why you have to create the dictionary then assign to the array.